# How to do Multiple Choice Using GridView android?

Tags: android, gridview, multiple-choice

This is how I do my Gridview with adapter, can someone tell me how can I modify these code to get the multiple choice effect ? Following is my code, kindly advise and thousand of thanks provided.

```
//privateList<Condiment> CondimentList;
CondimentList = getCondimentDescription(productcode); 
condimentGrid.setAdapter(new condimentlist());

 public class condimentlist extends BaseAdapter {

        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public condimentlist() {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(cart_list.this);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return CondimentList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.condiment_item, null);
            }

            Condiment myObj = CondimentList.get(position);
        Button CondimentItem  = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.condimentItem);
        CondimentItem.setText("" +myObj.getCondimentDescription());


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: why dont you try recycler view for it?

Comment: look at this http://www.grokkingandroid.com/statelistdrawables-for-recyclerview-selection/

Comment: what is the different if i using recycler view?

Comment: you just have to call gridlayout manager instead of lineallayout manager and it has many advantages over listview and gridview

Comment: if you want to show adapter item as selected then just listen the onClick event of item and inside callback listener you can update the state of item as selected and inside getView you can check if item is selected then show some selected kind of overlay over item or whatever is your design requirement. If you want to achieve something else please define clearly.

Comment: @Avi What I want is when i click on the button in Gridview, the button will change color, then if I click the same button again, the button will change to original button color.

Comment: @Avi And also save the state of button, that's mean when i close the app and open the app, there will show the color of button when I click before.

Comment: @Avi Is it possible if i store the state using sqlite?

Comment: I hope you are having model for each item of gridview you can keep the state in the model of GridView Item selected with true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Just little addition in your code provide selected value in your Condiment class model and use like this.

```
//privateList<Condiment> CondimentList;
CondimentList = getCondimentDescription(productcode); 
condimentGrid.setAdapter(new condimentlist());

 public class condimentlist extends BaseAdapter {

        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public condimentlist() {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(cart_list.this);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return CondimentList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.condiment_item, null);
            }

            final Condiment myObj = CondimentList.get(position);
            Button CondimentItem  = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.condimentItem);
            CondimentItem.setText("" +myObj.getCondimentDescription());
            CondimentItem.setSelected(myObj.isSelected());
            CondimentItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myObj.setSelected(!myObj.isSelected());
                    v.setSelected(myObj.isSelected());
                }
            });


        return convertView;
    }

}
```